# Invalid credentials using PHP with the Google apps reseller api

Tags: google-reseller-api

I'm trying to build a couple of webpages to gather info about our GApps customers.

I have all the code needed to get an Oauth token and it even seems to work (at least i can read all my calendar events using the calendar API). When i try to access the reseller api i get so far that i get the token but if i try to access the [userinfo](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo/),
passing the access_token parameter i get an `Invalid Credentials` error.

Unfortunately I haven't found much usable documentation on PHP but after all the auth procedure i'm trying to get the data via CURL...

Any ideas what's wrong or what i should do differently?

---

Still stuck so i thought i'd add the code i'm running now:

```
<?php
require_once '../google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';
require_once '../google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_ResellerService.php';
session_name('reseller');
session_start();

$debug=1;

$clientId='******.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$clientSecret='******';
$redirectURI='*****'; //links to the directory wehere the script is
$key='********';
$scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.order.readonly';
n
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Reseller PHP Starter Application");

$client->setClientId($clientId);
$client->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirectURI);
$client->setDeveloperKey($key);
$client->setScopes($scopes);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
if($debug)  echo "we have a code! <br />";

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  //echo $_SESSION['token']."<br/>";
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
  exit();
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
echo "access token settato<br/>";
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $mytoken=json_decode($_SESSION['token'], true);

  echo "DEBUG SESSION token:".$_SESSION['token']."<br />";
  echo "DEBUG token: ".$mytoken['access_token']."<br />";

  $domain='******'; //mydomain
  //key id defiend above
  $fields=array('customerId');
  $url="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo/?access_token=".$mytoken['access_token'];

  echo $url."<br />";

  $ch = curl_init($url);
  $scopes&state=antani&access_type=online&approval_prompt=auto");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer: '.$mytoken['access_token'],
    ));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "*******"); //server URL
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

 $resellerService = new Google_ResellerService($client);

if ($debug){
echo "<pre>";
  print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
}


} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}



if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
}


session_destroy();
?>
```

Any ideas as to why i still get the "insufficient permissions" error?

thanks!

Comment: and i found out thanks to a friend i was missing the userinfo scope... at least it's returning something which makes sense now instead of an insufficient permission. will update.

Comment: one step ahead and i found another lock up...i can create a $subscription element by calling : "$subscriptions = $resellerService->subscriptions;" but if i try to call the listSubscription() method it fails with an uncaught exception returning, once again, a 403 forbidden error.